# Processing Raw Input in a DLL in a separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, dll, raw-input

There is a GUI application, I need to process Raw Input in a DLL in a separate thread.

The problem is that when processing messages in a separate DLL thread, the main program window freezes while the thread is active.

Interestingly, if I do not register the Raw device, the main window does not freeze.

I am attaching a file with the Visual Studio 2019 demo project.

[RawProblem.zip](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/7dxLLSfHLtrrlQ)

DLL:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "hcsn.h"

using namespace std;

#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>


std::atomic_bool hook_STATUS = false; // 1 запущен, 0 прекратить выполнение



HWND window = 0;
HMODULE HMODULE_DLL = 0;

// for Test
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcChild(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    
    switch (message) {

    case WM_INPUT: {}
    default: DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); 
    }
    return 0;
}


int RawThread() {

    
    // ==================== CREATE NEW WINDOW FOR ROW_MSG =================

    HINSTANCE hInstance = HMODULE_DLL;  // GetModuleHandleW(nullptr);

    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc; // WndProcChild; //DefWindowProc;
    window_class.hInstance = hInstance; //GetModuleHandleW(nullptr) getThisModuleHandle() hInstance; 
    window_class.lpszClassName = L"DupOnlyMsg";
    window_class.style = CS_GLOBALCLASS;
    if (!RegisterClass(&window_class)) return -1; else OutputDebugStringA("CREATE CLASS\n");

//  window = CreateWindowEx(0, L"button", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 , 0);

    window = ::CreateWindowExW(0, window_class.lpszClassName, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, nullptr, hInstance, 0); // hInstance
    if (window == nullptr) return -1; else OutputDebugStringA("CREATE WINDOW\n");

    // ====================== REGISTRATION ==============================

    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid[2] = {};
    rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY | RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01; // HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC
    rid[0].usUsage = 0x02; // HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE
    rid[0].hwndTarget = window;

    rid[1].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY | RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    rid[1].usUsagePage = 0x01; // HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC
    rid[1].usUsage = 0x06; // KEYBORD
    rid[1].hwndTarget = window;

    if (RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, static_cast<UINT>(std::size(rid)), sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE))) OutputDebugStringA("REGISTRATION RAW\n");

    // ====================== MAIN MSG LOOP ==============================

    MSG event;
    int bRet;
    while (1==1) {  
        while ((bRet = GetMessage(&event, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {      
            if (event.message == WM_INPUT) { OutputDebugStringA("ok,"); } // Proceccing
            TranslateMessage(&event);
            DispatchMessage(&event);
        }
    }

    // =========================== EXIT ==================================

    if (window > 0) {
        DestroyWindow(window);
        window = 0;
        UnregisterClass(window_class.lpszClassName, window_class.hInstance);
    }

    return 0;
}

DLLAPI int hook_RUN(int* STATUS)
{
    if (*STATUS == 1) {
        hook_STATUS = true;
        thread thr(RawThread); thr.detach();
        return 1;
    }

    if (*STATUS == 0) {
        hook_STATUS = false;    
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        HMODULE_DLL = hModule;
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Base App:

```
// testGUI.cpp : Определяет точку входа для приложения.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "testGUI.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "../hcsn/hcsn.h";

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
#define NOMINMAX
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN


// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // ==================================================================================
    // ==================================================================================
    // ==================================================================================
    // Get console window:
    FILE* console_output;
    FILE* console_error;

    if (AllocConsole()) {
        freopen_s(&console_output, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        freopen_s(&console_error, "CONERR$", "w", stderr);
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    int itsint = 1;
    hook_RUN(&itsint);
    // ==================================================================================
    // ==================================================================================
    // ==================================================================================
    
    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TESTGUI, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TESTGUI));

    MSG msg;

    // Цикл основного сообщения:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Регистрирует класс окна.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TESTGUI));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TESTGUI);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   ЦЕЛЬ: Сохраняет маркер экземпляра и создает главное окно
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В этой функции маркер экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится главное окно программы.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить маркер экземпляра в глобальной переменной

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  ЦЕЛЬ: Обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT    - Отрисовка главного окна
//  WM_DESTROY  - отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int itsint = 1;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:

                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Добавьте сюда любой код прорисовки, использующий HDC...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Does it matter that the code for the thread is in a DLL? That said, you're making a (possibly fatal) mistake: You `#define` things like `NOMINMAX` _after_ including the header files which those macros are intendended to influence, so at that point it's too late. I'd suggest you define those more globally, typically in the project settings so they become part of the commandline.

Comment: thx for feedback, I deleted all macros, but unfortunately this does not solve the problem. and yes, the thread is unfortunately needed in the dll.

Comment: OutputDebugStringA() does not process anything.  So you get the WM_INPUT message over and over again, the message loop burns 100% core without making progress.  You have to call GetRawInputData or GetRawInputBuffer.